# doc.ready() and parseHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So it seems like when retrieving some html via ajax and inserting it into the page using `.html(parseHtml(result,true));`, that the javascript inside the result is executed without regard for doc.ready.

I'm guessing this is because the parent page itself is already "ready" and there is no concept/implementation of ready event for HTML fragments+script being inserted into the page via parseHtml.

I tested this like so.  Usually you'd expect the output to be 1, 3, 2, because the doc ready would occur last, but the output I get is 1,2,3.  Could be purely coincidence though.

```
console.log('1');

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('2');
});
console.log('3');
```

Some code is not working properly in doc.ready for initializing a tinyMce editor, but it works fine if I put a 500ms delay on it to fake a wait for doc.ready.  So it seems like an issue where the javascript is running too soon before the new html is integrated into the DOM.  Obviously this setTimeout is a hack that won't work consistently.

So my question is:

**Does .html($.parseHtml respect doc.ready inside the result, in that it waits for the new html to be ready in the DOM for running that script?
Is there some other way to include script inside a ajax html result and have it wait to run until the added html is "ready" in the dom?**

Comment: Your guess is correct. Once the initial document is loaded, `document.ready()` just executes its function immediately. It's not relevant to the AJAX document being loaded. However, I believe that `.load()` doesn't execute any of the Javascript until all the HTML has been insert into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  As far as .load I tested and am looking at the source and it looks like it just does `.html(`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js#L58

I was trying to keep everything encapsulated in the partial HTML, but looks like I should just pull the javascript out into its own js file loaded and called by the parent page so I can control when it runs.

Comment: You have to follow the code very carefully. jQuery extracts all the `<script>` tags out of the HTML before calling `.html()`. It then creates a `<script>` node to execute all the scripts that it found.

Comment: Actually, I think it may be `.html()` that does this. It needs to treat scripts specially, because assigning to `.innerHTML` doesn't execute scripts.

Comment: It only excludes scripts if you passed a selector, notice the ternary operator.  If a selector was passed then it selects that html fragment  from the result and .html that, if no selector is specified, then it runs the second part of the ternary, which is `.html` loading the entire result as well as executing the script, essentially doing the same thing I am doing, retrieving from a url, then loading the result via .html

Comment: That's what I said: `.html` extracts the scripts from the HTML so it can execute them.

Comment: So we agree .load doesn't delay the execution of scripts, but delegates to .html. Corrent me if I'm wrong, but I'm looking at the source code for .html now, if it finds scripts in the value it skips innerHtml if scripts found line 416:`!rnoInnerhtml`), then instead sets the elements contents via .append, but I lose track after that because so much jumping around: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L439

Comment: I told you it's complicated. I think the relevant code is at the end of `domManip` after `if (hasScripts)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately.

Note that this refers to the DOM in general. When you're loading additional elements later using AJAX, the DOM is still in its initialized state, so the above applies.

If you use `.load()` to load HTML that contains `<script>` elements, I believe all the scripts will be executed after the other elements have been added to the DOM. So there's no need to use `$(document).ready()` in these scripts, but there should be no harm in doing so.

Comment: As far as the last part, is seems like you're implying .load will behave differently than .html.  My point is .load just calls .html, so .load doesn't do anything .html doesn't as far as script processing.  As far as my own testing it appears .load behaves the same as .ajax.done(.html)

Comment: I never implied that. `.load()` is just shorthand for `.ajax()` + `.html()`.

Comment: No not what I said.  "you're implying .load will behave differently than .html"  Keyword differently.

Comment: If I implied that, it was unintentional. In a comment above I wrote "Actually, I think it may be .html() that does this" where "this" refers to deferring execution of Javascript until all the rest of the HTML is added to the DOM.

Comment: What I meant was: .load uses .html, and .html defers exection of scripts, so this implies that .load also does.